# Python Write terminal output to file then read file

Tags: python, file

I'm having trouble writing the terminal output (all print statements) to a textfile then reading that textfile in the same script. I keep getting an I/O error if I close the program to finish writing to the file and then re-open the file to read it, or no output for the final print(file_contents) statement.

Here's my code:

```
import sys

filename = open("/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt", 'r+')

filename.truncate()

sys.stdout = filename

print('Hello')

print('Testing')

filename.close()

with open("/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(file)
```

Any suggestions would be great! I'm planning to use this to print output's from some longer scripts to a slack channel.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific IO Error you end with?

Comment: Hi Vinny,
The error I get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "terminaldump", line 25, in <module>
    print(file)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import sys

filename = open("/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt", 'w')

sys_out = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = filename

print('Hello')

print('Testing')

print('Test')

filename.close()

sys.stdout = sys_out

with open("/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt", 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data)

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is:
`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt'` because:
file open mode `r+` does not create a file. Use mode `w` like this:

You have to reattach `stdout` to console again to print in console.

```
import sys

filename = open('/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt', 'w')

# filename.truncate()  # mode 'w' truncates file

sys.stdout = filename

print('Hello')

print('Testing')

filename.close()

# reattach stdout to console
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

with open('/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data)
```

will print:

```
Hello  
Testing
```

Comment: Hi Elis,
I've changed the open file type to write (w) which does write to the file but doesn't seem to be able to read it without producing the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "terminaldump", line 25, in <module>
    print(file)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

The second part of the code fails as it says the file has already been closed, however there's no way to read the file after writing to it without the close method.

Thanks

Comment: @JamesLovesPython Try, this new code. I have reattached `stdout` to console again.

Comment: No longer throwing the I/O error, however nothing printed to the console.
I added seek(0) to make sure it reads from the beginning and checked the text file to confirm that information has been written to the file. Here's the updated code:

import sys
filename = open('/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt', 'w')
sys.stdout = filename
print('Hello')
print('Testing')
filename.close()
# reattach stdout to console
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

with open('/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt') as file:
    file.seek(0)
    data = file.read()
    print(data)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you redirect `sys.stdout` to `filename`, and then you close the file. Afterwards you can't print anything anymore, since the file is closed.

```
sys.stdout = filename
..
..
filename.close()

with open("/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(file)
```

The last print statement tries to *print* output to *sys.stdout*, which is a closed file.

If you want to get the old behavior back, you need to keep a reference to `sys.stdout`. This will solve it:

```
sys_out = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = filename
..
..
filename.close()

sys.stdout = sys_out

with open("/Users/xxx/documents/python/dump.txt") as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(file)
```

Comment: Great! That worked! Thanks for your help Vinny & Elis :)

Comment: @JamesLovesPython Wondering how do you got that working with `print(file)`. What do you think this is printing?

Comment: Hi Elis,
I included the print statement at the end to make sure a string was populated with the file contents collected from stdout during runtime so that I can send the output to my Slack channel. I've inserted this at various points in try/exceptions to send me the output of the console when something fails or runs successfully and I want the details.

Comment: @JamesLovesPython You did not answer my question!

Comment: Sorry Elis, don't think I understood your question could you explain again and I'll answer?
Thanks!